# Dropdown List Select index Default if no User Input

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a dropdown list which works fine if the user selects one of the 6 options.
However if no action is taken because the first Option is the one required the selected value stays blank.

I have tried to set default selected value and search other solutions via Stack Overflow. Code Project, etc. but nothing works.
it may be something basic in my code!

```
    static string prevPage = String.Empty;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload1.Attributes["multiple"] = "multiple";

        txtUN.Text = Request.QueryString["SVCCNo"];
        lblid.Text = Session["username"].ToString();
        txtCID.Text = Request.QueryString["CID"];
        lblCID.Text = Request.QueryString["CID"];
        lblSeparator.Text = " - ";
        lblLocation.Text = Request.QueryString["LName"];
        lblAssetName.Text = Request.QueryString["SVCCIDName"];

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SVCCAssetsDb"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conn);
        sqlcon.Open();
        //lblType.Text = "1";

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            //move lbl inside loop
            int uniquenuumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtUN.Text);

            HttpPostedFile postedFile = Request.Files[i];
            if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //lblType.Text = txtType.Text;
                int txttype = 1;
                txttype = Convert.ToInt32(lblType.Text);
                string userid = lblid.Text;
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/") + fileName);
                lblMessage.Text += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> uploaded.<br />", fileName);

                string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Attachment (UserName, FilePath, UniqueNumber, TypeCode) VALUES ('" + userid + "', + '" + fileName + "', + '" + uniquenuumber + "', '" + txttype + "')";
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlcon);

                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        sqlcon.Close();
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtType.Text))
        txtType.Text = selectedValue;
        lblType.Text = txtType.Text;
    }

    protected void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(prevPage);
    }
}
```

aspx code: 
    
        
        
            Multi-File Upload
        
        
        
        Files Must be All of the Same Type e.g. Photographs
        
            
            
        
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            Select the File Type Before Selecting the Files to Upload 
            Otherwise Files Chosen will be Clear Cleared

Comment: Could you add your aspx front code ?

Comment: Thanks Gregory This is as much as I can put in this Box: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownDocumentType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataDocumentType" DataTextField="Content" DataValueField="TypeCode" Height="26px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="638px">
            </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Gregory i have had a thought that if on Page Load I set dropdown list selected item = 2 then at some other point i set it to 1 it might fire. As a night owl I am tired and going to bed now but will try it later.

Comment: Gregory thanks for your support. Worked it out in the end. Jim

Answer (score 0):

From what I guess without having the front code :

You're having a problem with this line :

```
int txttype = 1;
txttype = Convert.ToInt32(lblType.Text);
```

Which is caused because if you don't select another item from your dropdown, your label isn't updated and so this create a problem ?

If that's the case (else just explain me where I'm wrong )

You could just do a first intialisation of your label Type at the page load (in the !Page.IsPostBack Condition !!)

```
lblType.Text = "Your Default value as string";
```

Indeed, the select index changed event will trigger only if you change the dropdown, which in the case, if you stay on the first item, will not be triggered.

But there's maybe something else, let's try that first ! :)

Comment: Thanks but No that is something I have tried. But when you chage the document type after that to add more to some other type e.g. option 5 it returns blank/null.

Comment: Well i think we miss some informations to help you. You should try to debug your code and be more precise in your explaination about what you're trying to do, what is the context of the page.

Comment: The context of the page is to upload files to the database and update a SQL table with Document, Name, Document Type and Asset Number. As this involves 1000's of Files of different types they are divided into Photo's, Manuals, Drawings, etc. 6 Categories for the user to select.

Comment: Okay, and your problem ? Which case exactly create a problem ? What happend and what you were expecting instead ?

Comment: Any of them. The main problem is that there seems no way to set a Default for an Option when the User does not change the dropdown list

Comment: Gregory i have had a thought that if on Page Load I set dropdown list selected item = 2 then at some other point i set it to 1 it might fire. As a night owl I am tired and going to bed now but will try it later. –

Answer (score 0):

```
 SOLVED! Just a matter of getting the Code Rejigged.
 Code Now Reads:
        string conn = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SVCCAssetsDb"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conn);
        sqlcon.Open();
        int txttype = Convert.ToInt32(lblType.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            //move lbl inside loop
            int uniquenuumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtUN.Text);

            HttpPostedFile postedFile = Request.Files[i];
            if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //lblType.Text = txtType.Text;
                //int txttype = 1;
                txttype = Convert.ToInt32(lblType.Text);
                string userid = lblid.Text;
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/") + fileName);
                lblMessage.Text += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> uploaded.<br />", 
    fileName);

                string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Attachment (UserName, FilePath, 
    UniqueNumber, TypeCode) VALUES ('" + userid + "', + '" + fileName + "', + '" + 
   uniquenuumber + "', '" + txttype + "')";
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlcon);

                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        sqlcon.Close();
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtType.Text))
        txtType.Text = selectedValue;
        lblType.Text = selectedValue;
    }
```